# Trying to develop the syntax to update one table with values from another table based on a join of a third table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Test case below shows construction of tables.  I need to update the address data in `tab_1` based on a join on `tab_2` and `_3`.  The update script shown returns **'missing right parenthesis'**, and I am certain it points to an error in the syntax.  Would appreciate any help or guidance in getting the statement to properly update the base table.

```
create table tab_1(address varchar2(25), city varchar2(25), state varchar2(2),zip varchar2(10), office_id varchar2(25));

create table tab_2 (company varchar2(25), office varchar2(25), address_id varchar2(5), office_id varchar2(5));

create table tab_3 (address_id varchar2(5), address varchar2(25), city varchar2(25), state varchar2(2),zip varchar2(10));


insert into tab_1(office_id) values(46);

insert into tab_2(company, office, address_id, office_id) 
    values('Stone', 'north', '45', '15');
insert into tab_3(address_id, address, city, state, zip) 
    values('15', '12Main', 'York', 'NY', '12345');


ALTER TABLE TAB_1 ADD 
CONSTRAINT tab_1_PK
 PRIMARY KEY (OFFICE_ID)
 ENABLE
 VALIDATE;

 ALTER TABLE TAB_2 ADD 
CONSTRAINT tab_2_PK
 PRIMARY KEY (OFFICE_ID)
 ENABLE
 VALIDATE;

ALTER TABLE TAB_3 ADD 
CONSTRAINT tab_3_PK
 PRIMARY KEY (ADDRESS_ID)
 ENABLE
 VALIDATE;




update (select tab_3.address, tab_3.city, tab_3.state, tab_3.zip, tab_1.address,     tab_1.city, tab_1.state, tab_1.zip
        FROM
    INNER JOIN tab_1 ON (tab_1.office_id=tab_2.office.id) 
    INNER JOIN tab_3 ON (tab_2.address_id = tab_3.address_id))
        SET tab_1.address=tab_3.address, tab_1.city=tab_3.city, tab_1.state=tab_3.state, tab_1.zip=tab_3.zip;


UPDATE ( SELECT src.x src_x, src.y src_y , tgt.x tgt_x, tgt.y tgt_y FROM src 
INNER JOIN tgt ON ( src.id = tgt.id ) ) SET tgt_x = src_x , tgt_y = src_y

*******************************************************

UPDATE tab_1
   SET (address,
        city,
        state,
        zip) =
          (SELECT (address, city, state, zip)
             FROM tab_3, tab2
            WHERE     tab_1.office_id = tab_2.office_id
                  AND tab_2.address_id = tab_3.address_id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two `update` statements are incomplete - they don't even specify which table to update. They're so far off I'm afraid I'm going to ignore them as I don't see how they're salvagable *8-)

Your third as an extra set of parentheses; you don't need them (and they aren't valid) around the list of columns you're selecting in the subquery, it's trying to interpret that as a further subquery which doesn't exist. You also have a typo in one of the table names:

```
UPDATE tab_1
   SET (address, city, state, zip) =
       (SELECT address, city, state, zip
          FROM tab_3, tab_2
         WHERE tab_1.office_id = tab_2.office_id
           AND tab_2.address_id = tab_3.address_id);
```

I'd suggest you use modern `join` syntax, especially if this is fairly new and you haven't learned (arguably) bad habits yet:

```
UPDATE tab_1
   SET (address, city, state, zip) =
       (SELECT address, city, state, zip
          FROM tab_2
          JOIN tab_3
            ON tab_3.address_id = tab_2.address_id
         WHERE tab_2.office_id = tab_1.office_id);
```

Comment: "Modern" join syntax has been here since 1996! The original form is practically prehistoric.